# No matching distribution found for xyzservices during installation

Tags: python, macos, pip

When I try `pip3 install xyzservices` I receive:

```
Collecting xyzservices
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xyzservices (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for xyzservices
```

`python --version` returns:

```
Python 3.6.8
```

`pip3 --version` returns:

```
pip 18.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All versions of `xyzservices` require Python >= 3.7. Even the oldest version [`2021.7`](https://pypi.org/project/xyzservices/2021.7/). See [the code](https://github.com/geopandas/xyzservices/blob/bb46d273a7c861a3c6dd80e9e42411e40330e15e/setup.py#L33) at the oldest tag [`2021.7`](https://github.com/geopandas/xyzservices/tree/2021.07).

Comment: Also already visible on the pypi page in the left column under `Meta`